# how to pass string from activity to fragment?

Tags: android

Activity A

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ActivityA);

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("mobile", "123456789");
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA ();
    fragmentA .setArguments(b);}
```

FragmentA

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmentA, container, false);

        String txtMobile = getArguments().getString("mobile");
        Log.i("mobile2",txtMobile);
        mobile.setText(txtMobile);}
```

I have tried above solution but showing error that 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be It's about the way you are adding fragment to the class:

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("mobile", "123456789");
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA ();
    fragmentA .setArguments(b);

    fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(placeholder, new FragmentA(), tabId)
    .commit();
```

can you provide more data about how did you add it ?

Comment: fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FragmentA()).commit();

Comment: that's the problem: fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragmentA).commit(); notice the fragmentA instead of a new instance of FragmentA,

Answer (score 0):

Create your fragment like this

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String string) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("string",string);
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And then in Fragment `onCreate` use `getArguments()` for pulling that String. Don't forget to check `getArguments()` for null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch the argument in onCreate method of fragment with default value constructor:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String txtMobile = getArguments().getString("mobile", "");
}
```

and make sure you commit the fragment transaction after settting the arguments in fragment. :)

Comment: can you show me your code , how you are commiting the fragment?

Comment: fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager(); fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FragmentA()).commit();

Comment: `
Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("mobile", "123456789");
    FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA ();
    fragment.setArguments(b);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
`

Answer (score 0):

First check that your argument is not null.
For example
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmentA, container, false);
```

if(getArguments()!=null){

```
    String txtMobile = getArguments().getString("mobile");
    Log.i("mobile2",txtMobile);
    mobile.setText(txtMobile);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null){            
            String txtMobile = savedInstanceState.getString("mobile");                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inteface to pass data from activity to fragment

In your activity

```
public interface FragmentRefreshListener {
    void onRefresh(String mydata);
}

public FragmentRefreshListener fragmentRefreshListener;

public void setFragmentRefreshListener(FragmentRefreshListener fragmentRefreshListener) {
    this.fragmentRefreshListener = fragmentRefreshListener;
}

public FragmentRefreshListener getFragmentRefreshListener() {
    return fragmentRefreshListener;
}
```

Then inside your fragment add below code

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFragmentRefreshListener(new MainActivity.FragmentRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh(String mydata) {

      // write your logic here

        }
    });
```

use following in your activity to pass data from activity to fragment

```
getFragmentRefreshListener().onRefresh("dummy text");
```